# Why can't devices under different TP-Link routers of the same mesh access each other?

Tags: router, mesh

I build a mesh network with two TP-Link AX5400 routers，all devices can access internet as expected. Route A is main router, whose ip address is 192.168.0.1, and route B has an ip adress 192.168.0.2.

Devices under router can access each other, and devices under router B can access each other, but devices under route B could not access devices under route A, vice versa.

Said B1 is under route B and A1 is under route A.

Network configuration of B1:
IP: 192.168.0.8
GATEWAY: 192.168.0.1
MASK: 255.255.255.0

Network configuration of A1:
IP: 192.168.0.3
GATEWAY: 192.168.0.1
MASK: 255.255.255.0

I can manage router A via web interface or mobile app, while I can't manager router B. I guess it's managed by route A.

Is there any method to make A1 and B1 accessible by each other? Thank you.

I tried to ping A1 from B1, but failed.
A tracert command also failed.